# Shared Access Database over Network

Tags: ms-access, networking

Sharing a Database over a network. Shared is turned on however when others open database none of the buttons work. No error comes up it just flashes and nothing happens.

I am looking for my database to be opened and operated by more than one user.

Comment: It's possible VBA is not allowed on these user's pc's. You can set the location of the file to be a trusted location and set macro security to allow trusted locations in \file,Options,Trust Centre,Trust Centre Settings, Trusted Locations

Comment: This didnt work. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was that the pop up of the form after the button was pressed wasn't appearing on the screen as apposed to there being any kind of access issue. Just in case anyone else experiences the same thing.